# Convert Date Format in Different Format PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am new in PHP and Learning to convert datetime in different format
I have date time like this

My Date Input is like

```
03/12/2020 23:18
```

Which I need like

```
 2020-12-03 23:18:00
```

So I am trying like

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($appointment_date));
```

But its giving me date like

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show your exact code. [I cannot duplicate the issue](https://3v4l.org/7778c)

Comment: @aynber Sorry, I have edited question. Thanks!

Comment: So you want it to be interpreted as dd/mm/yyyy rather than mm/dd/yyyy? PHP has no way of knowing which format you are using. It assumes mm/dd/yyyy by default. By the way, that code doesn't produce the output you're claiming - it produces 12th Match instead of 3rd December - https://3v4l.org/qe5O2.  Use DateTime::createFromFormat to parse the date, then you can specify the incoming format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the DateTime format method:

```
$incoming_date = '12/12/2020 23:18';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $incoming_date . ':00');
$outgoing_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I'm about 95% sure you can also leave off the seconds, but I can't say for sure without testing it:

```
$incoming_date = '12/12/2020 23:18';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $incoming_date);
$outgoing_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```